# Another Samba permission denied error

Tags: linux, permissions, network-shares, samba

This is my first attempt at setting up a samba share without some fancy gui doing all the heard work for me. This needs to be a secured share that a Windows Server 2003 system can access (don't ask).

```
User  : smbuser
Group : smbgroup
Share : /TEMP/smb/share
```

smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = filestor
security = user
map to guest = bad user
#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[Share]
 comment = Stuff
 path = /TEMP/smb/share
 valid users = @smbgroup
 read only = no
 guest ok = no
 writable = yes
 browsable = no
```

Permissions

```
[root@filestor TEMP]# ls -al /TEMP/smb/
total 14
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root    root     3 Dec 21 13:47 .
drw-------. 8 root    root     8 Dec 21 13:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 smbuser smbgroup 2 Dec 21 13:47 share
```

user info

```
[root@filestor TEMP]# groups smbuser
smbuser : smbgroup
```

If I allow browsing, Windows can see the share but can not connect with a permissions error.

Any help would be appreciated

testparm

```
[root@filestor ~]# testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[share]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    server string = Samba Server %v
    security = USER
    map to guest = Bad User
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[share]
    comment = Stuff
    path = /TEMP/smb/share
    valid users = @smbgroup
    admin users = smbuser
    read only = No
    browseable = No
```

Comment: Why have you not made the share browsable? Also, what does `testparm` say?

Comment: I noticed on the `.. (/TEMP)` permission is `drw-------` you will typically need at least execute permission to traverse into a directory

Comment: @EddieDunn I updated the permissions to 7777 (not permanent, but for troubleshooting) and sadly I am still locked out.

Comment: @BigChris I updated my post to reflect testparm.

Comment: What do you mean "locked out".... when you're asked for the username/password are you entering the username as in `filestor\smbuser`?

Comment: Browsable=no will make it not show up in a net show or similar... Is that what you mean?

Comment: @BigChris When entering "\\filestor\share" in the  the "run" command in windows I am prompted for a username/password. Using either "filestor\smbuser" or just "smbuser" give me a windows stating that I need to contact the server admin about permissions. (I have an entry in the hosts file for this)

Comment: @EddieDunn I am unable to modify the /TEMP directory as this holds several FTP, SFTP, and NFS shares. This server was put together as a temporary solution while the actual servers are built. But I will play around with another share to see if that is the case.

Comment: Just move it to another place nto in /TEMP to test.

Comment: @EddieDunn I ended up creating another share "/sharetest" with the same results. I am authenticated but I do not have any permissions on the share it'self.

Comment: Did you run smbpasswd at any point?

Comment: Yes, smbpasswd has been run on the smbuser account.

Comment: have you tried naming the share somthing other than `share`? it seems like that might overload a reserved word. just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to what Eddie Dunn pointed out, the permissions on the /TEMP directory. Not entirely sure how to manipulate the permissions on /TEMP to allow samba access to the sub directory /TEMP/smb/share.

For now I will use the root user account for the share as it is only being used by one other server, when we get the permanent servers in place I will revisit the problem.

Thanks everyone for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: `chmod a+x /TEMP`. It's meaningless to have a directory with `rw` permissions but no `x`.